# Custom Form Request Validation with unique validation not working on update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I have a custom form request validation that I'm using in for Create and Update record with unique column validation. It's working fine for creating new record, but not for updating a record.

**Custome Form Request**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
class ServiceTypeRequest extends FormRequest
{

public function authorize()
{
    return true;
}

/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'service_name'        => ['required', Rule::unique('service_type', 'Service')->ignore($this->service_type) ],
        'type'                => ['required', 'string'],
        'view_availability'   => ['required', 'boolean'],

    ];
 }
}
```

**Controller Update**

```
public function update(ServiceTypeRequest $request, ServiceType $serviceType)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $service_type = ServiceType::update([
        'Service'               => $validated['service_name'],
        'type'                  => $validated['type'],
        'view_availability'     => $validated['view_availability'],
    ]);

    return redirect()
            ->route('service_type.index')
            ->with('status', 'Service type updated!');
}
```

**Getting error when I submit the update form with PUT method** It's complaining about the `$this` I have this inside the custom form validation for service_name.

```
Error
Using $this when not in object context
http://localhost:8021/service_type/58
```

Comment: Try ->ignore($this->get('service_type'))

Comment: that isn't a static method so it is in an object context ... is that the line the error is saying is causing that?

Comment: The error message gives you the stack trace; there must be somewhere in your code where you're calling `ServiceTypeRequest::rules()`. Also worth noting that, invalid data will never get to your controller so there's no point in calling `$request->validated()`.

Comment: And right now you're checking if the value of `$request->service_name` matches a value in the `Service` column of the `service_type` table, but ignoring any records where the `id` column is equal to `$request->service_type`. Is that correct? Your database setup is very non-conventional if so. In SQL terms, the validation fails if `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM service_type WHERE Service = '$request->service_name' AND id != '$request->service_type';` returns > 0.

Comment: And one final note, `ServiceType::update()` is going to update every single row in your database. I assume you wanted to do `$serviceType->update()` instead?

Comment: The error you are providing is very starange beacause when you inject a ```FormRequest``` class to controller method it will auomatically create a new object. But the Error seems bit odd to me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing ServiceType object in custom form request. Here I have passed ServiceType object in form request and updating it from controller update method.

**Custom Form Request**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Models\ServiceType;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class ServiceTypeRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules(ServiceType $serviceType)
    {                   
        return [
            'service_name'        => ['required', Rule::unique('service_type', 'Service')->ignore($serviceType) ],
            'type'                => ['required', 'string'],
            'view_availability'   => ['required', 'boolean'],
    
        ];
    }
}
```

**Controller update method**

```
public function update(ServiceTypeRequest $request, ServiceType $serviceType)
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    $service_type = $serviceType->update([
        'Service'               => $validated['service_name'],
        'type'                  => $validated['type'],
        'view_availability'     => $validated['view_availability'],
    ]);

    return redirect()
            ->route('service_type.index')
            ->with('status', 'Service type updated!');
}
```